# Extending size (area) of raster using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, area

My problem is that I would like to multiply two rasters using raster calculation tool. Both rasters have values 0 and 1, but the covered area of first raster is bigger (100 x 100 miles) then the area of second (80 x 80 miles).

How can I extend the second raster to the same size?

I would just like to add columns and rows with 0. At first I thought that this would be simple, but after searching on internet I didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on your layer > Properties > Extent tab

From here you can set your raster extent to that of another layer. You can then use the [Conditional tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) to assign whatever value you like to the extra pixels, which default to NoData. Further [instruction here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009z000000ms000000.htm).

Depending on your application you may need to also implement the [IsNull tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/Is_Null/009z000000m8000000/).

[image]