# How to force extent of multiband image to match the extent of another image?

Tags: raster

I have two 8bit unsigned integer 4-band raster images that overlap (Raster 1 and Raster 2). One of the images is slightly smaller than the other (Raster 1). How can I extend the extent of the smaller raster (Raster 1) to match the extent of the larger raster (Raster 2)? The extended area in Raster 1 should contain 0 values for all the bands. NoData values are not wanted in this case. I use ArcGIS/Spatial Analyst, QGIS and any open source tools.

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with the rasters when they have the same size?

Comment: @MarceloVilla Tile them.

Comment: Setting the `extent` variable in the environment settings should be enough. For example `arcpy.env.extent = 'Raster2.tif'`

Comment: @MarceloVilla Setting the environment for which tool?

Comment: Do you use gdalwarp?

Comment: @NathanThomas Sure.

Comment: you can set the limits of the smaller image to be those of the larger image using -te

Comment: Also see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79622/extend-the-size-area-of-raster).

Comment: @RJJoling What makes this a unique situation is that I am working with multiband imagery rather than single band imagery.

Comment: @Aaron Using `RasterCalculator` works but the output cointains NoData values instead of 0's. I guess you could read your raster as a `NumPy` array and then mask the NoData with 0's.

Comment: @MarceloVilla Unfortunately, the raster calculator will output a single band raster.

Comment: @Aaron It might be a little bit tedious but you could do it for each band and then join together again... Not even the `ApplyEnvironment` tool keeps multiple bands when used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdalwarp, such as:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -te minx miny maxx maxy input.tif output.tif
```

You can get the extents using:

```
gdalinfo reference.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully **Orfeo ToolBox** is also on your list, of which **Superimpose** function fits smaller raster (your *Raster 1*) to a larger raster (your *Raster 2*).

(Allow me to show it in **Monteverdi** GUI, as I am not good at using it in QGIS processing - OTB mode).

[image]

There is a `Fill Value` option which fills the outside of smaller raster by the user defined value (coincidentally, default value is 0.0).